# Cucumber JS: Custom parameter types not matching

Tags: javascript, typescript, cucumber, bdd, cucumberjs

I have some step definitions that use custom parameters.

```
const assertEntity = function(name: string, operator: string, 
                                                   otherName: string) {
    console.log(`assertAttrs with ${name} ${operator} ${otherName}`);
};

Then("{name} object is {operator} {otherName}", assertEntity);
```

And the following feature file (truncated)

```
Scenario: Compare two similar API key objects
    Given we have a new ApiKey called Red
```

And parameter types defined like this

```
defineParameterType({
    regexp: /name/,
    transformer: function(s) {
        return s;
    },
    name: "name"
});
```

However cucumber says step definition is undefined...

```
? Given we have a new ApiKey called Red
   Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

     Given('we have a new ApiKey called Red', function () {
       // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
       return 'pending';
     });
```

I believe the problem is in my regexp but I've seen this done in examples so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How the Transformers work**

1. The regex has to match the parameter
2. The cucumber expression has to match the step when converted back to a regex

You can use any variety of transformations. For instance:

```
Given I am on the "Home" page
Given I am on the "My Basket" page
```

Could both be matched by the transformer:

```
defineParameterType({
    regexp: /"([^"]*)"/,
    transformer(string) {
        return urls[string.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase()]
    },
    name: 'page',
    useForSnippets: false
});
```

The transformation that is happening here is the url is being located in an array of various urls.

**The Answer**

For your example, the step definition that you have provided wouldn't match the step that you have provided.

But, if we were to go ahead and match this:

```
Given we have a new ApiKey called "Red"
```

By using a step definition like this:

```
Given('we have a new ApiKey called {name}', function(){
     return pending
});
```

We would require a step transformer like this:

```
defineParameterType({
    regexp: /"([^"]*)"/,
    transformer: function(s) {
        return s;
    },
    name: "name",
    useForSnippets: false
});
```

**Note**: `"([^"]*)"` is not the be-all end-all of regex matching with Cucumber, but it was a fairly standard regex to be found within the step definitions before cucumber expressions came out with 3.x.x, hence the 2 examples I've used are with them.

Comment: Thanks, I worked this out with some poking. There's a Python library called Behave which will can do this for you. You define your step as "given I have {something} called {name}" and the function as `step(something, name)` which is what I was expecting here.

Comment: @KyleFairns and Alex Logan, I was trying to understand how to use this custom parameters in cucumber and I am a little confused. Can you please let me know in which file will my this code of defineParameterType go? I created feature file added your code then step definition file and added your code but not sure of this part - defineParameterType. Sorry I am new to cucumber and JS. Please help me.

Comment: In `features`, let's add a `support` directory . Then, for instance, `person_parameter.js` file is in there. This is what's kind of shown on the   stuff.