# In Cucumber where do I declare defineParameterType?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am learning to create a custom data type in cucumber and followed this post  [Cucumber JS: Custom parameter types not matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594271/cucumber-js-custom-parameter-types-not-matching) to learn how to do it.

I get below error.

```
? Given we have a new ApiKey called "Red"
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Given('we have a new ApiKey called {string}', function (string) {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });
```

feature file code-

```
Feature: Try
 @test
  Scenario: try custom parameter

    Given we have a new ApiKey called "Red"
```

step definition file-

```
const { Given } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');

    Given('we have a new ApiKey called {name}', function () {
      console.log('----Inside function---');
      return 'pending';
    });
```

ParameterType.js code -

```
const { defineParameterType } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');

        defineParameterType({
            regexp: /"([^"]*)"/,
            transformer: function(s) {
                return s;
            },
            name: "name",
            useForSnippets: false
        });
```

Comment: FYI — As it is your custom parameter type `{name}` is no better than the ones already available to you: `{string}` or `{word}`. The former will match anything between single or double quotes (including whitespaces). The latter matches any single word between single or double quotes. In both cases the quotes **are not** part of the match. In case it helps I wrote a little cookbook for Cucumber: https://github.com/customcommander/cucumber-js-cukebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did below things and my code worked.

1. I change this step definition to below part. I forgot to pass name as parameter so added it.
2. Not sure why but we have pre setup file written in setup folder where we have beforeAll written for our feature files, and I had to move my file PArameterTypes.js in that setup file.

   Given('we have a new ApiKey called {name}', function (name) {
   console.log('----Inside function---');
   return 'pending';
   });

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to declare it anywhere and Cucumber will pick it up.

> The recommended location to define custom parameter types, would be in `features/support/parameter_types.js`. This is just a convention though; Cucumber will pick them up from any file

Reference: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/ (choose JavaScript language at the top)

Comment: Gael I update my code , created new file parameterTypes.js as you said  and added defineParameterType in it but I get the error. I can't find that step definition. I also see error - Undefined Parameter type name

Comment: Please create a new question, do not update your question with a new question otherwise it makes no sense for future readers.

Comment: Gale yeah I shouldn't have done it. I will keep it in mind for the future questions. I only added all the code here. Please take a look. Many thanks.